# High CPU load all the time

Tags: cpu, cpu-load

My computer has an old dual-core CPU with `1 GiB` of RAM

On normal work, such as using firefox, the CPU usage is more than 50%, and if I open more than couple browser tabs, it happens lag because of the high CPU usage

Is it a normal CPU usage or there's something hung in the system? What can I do about it?

Comment: You have very little RAM for Ubuntu. Ubuntu needs around 2GB to be "lag free" because it caches a lot of data, and needs more memory to run smoothly than Windows.

Comment: did you install Ubuntu 64-bit with that low amount of RAM? I would upgrade the RAM to around 4GB or install Lubuntu.

Comment: If you just want to learn C. Install a server version and start coding, you will get much more speed out of the computer without a GUI. Or upgrade the RAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason for installing a lightweight version of Ubuntu such as Xubuntu or Lubuntu is to get better performance. If you want to get better performance, you should try using a lightweight *buntu version, even if your hardware will support Ubuntu and Unity.